# How To Have a Microsoft Report on Remote Server Network- Microsoft Report 2010 [rdlc]?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Hi
Really Iam very new to Microsoft Report. Before I used only Crystal report only. So I have no any idea.

Actaully from my system I used the below code and it works fine. But my program has to be accessed by 2 more users on network. On Network my program is working fine, no problem except report. For that I have no any idea, what else I need?
May be I need to install anything on my sqlserver installed machine in network?
or I have to install reportviewer to my users system ?
And any sample code for that?

Any Guidences will be happy.

Thanks For The Ideas.

Thanks & Regards
PARAMU

```
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource VehRDS = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
RepDS.Name = "DataSet1";
RepDS.Value = MyDataTable1;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(VehRDS);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath ="C:\\Documents and Settings\\...\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\MyProject\\My_Report.rdlc";
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
reportViewer1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251669.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install Merge Module for Crystal Report.

[Crystal Report MergeModule](https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100005853292008E/cr_net_2005_mm_mlb_x86.zip)

Then on your Deployment Project you need

[How to: Add Merge Modules to a Deployment Project](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-merge-module.htm)

Regards

Comment: Thanks... But I will ask another Question regarding reportviewer to clear all my doubts.